VBA: variable between two values is not evaluating correctly
My code is of courses that students take.  Depending on which course they take, a variable gets incremented.  I then need to check if this variable is a certain number. When the first row evaluates the variable is equal to 1 and it's executing the following code because it's somehow meeting the last condition? I need to figure out what I am messing up with my conditional "AND" statements.
Here is the chunk of code (not the complete code):
'Check for completer status
            ElseIf acc_comp >= 21 And acc_comp <= 25 Or _
                   pl_an_sys_comp = 50 Or _
                   pl_an_sys_comp = 60 Or _
                   auto_tech_comp >= 21 And auto_tech_comp <= 23 Or _
                   cul_art_comp >= 21 And cul_art_comp <= 25 Or _
                   dig_art_des_comp >= 21 And dig_art_des_comp <= 23 Or _
                   ece_comp >= 31 And ece_comp <= 37 Or _
                   envi_nat_res_comp = 40 Or _
                   envi_nat_res_comp = 50 Or _
                   gen_manag_comp >= 21 And gen_manag_comp <= 26 Or _
                   graph_comm_comp >= 21 Or graph_comm_comp <= 23 Or _
                   health_sci_comp >= 21 Or health_sci_comp <= 28 Or _
                   horti_comp = 40 Or _
                   horti_comp = 50 Or _
                   mark_manag_comp >= 21 And mark_manag_comp <= 24 Or _
                   mark_manag_comp = 30 Or _
                   media_tech_comp >= 21 And media_tech_comp <= 23 Or _
                   pltw_biomed_sci_comp >= 21 And pltw_biomed_sci_comp <= 26 Or _
                   pltw_pre_eng_comp >= 22 And pltw_pre_eng_comp <= 26 Or _
                   sports_med_comp >= 21 And sports_med_comp <= 27 Or _
                   fam_con_sci_comp >= 21 And fam_con_sci_comp <= 26 Or _
                   fam_con_sci_comp = 30 Or _
                   prog_soft_dev_comp >= 21 And prog_soft_dev_comp <= 25 Then
                    
                        pc.Activate
                        term_match = Application.Match(main.Cells(i, 14), pc.Range(Cells(4, 77), Cells(30, 77)), 0)
                        
                        If IsError(term_match) Then
                        ElseIf term_match > 0 Then
                        
                            If IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 3)) Then
                            
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 1) = main.Cells(i, 1)
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 3) = "Y"

I will also include a picture to show the count of prog_soft_dev_comp as I go through it.

I understand that prog_soft_dev_comp is <= 25, but I was hoping that the value of 1 would not evaluate in that last line, but it seems like it is? Am I writing this incorrectly? I looked at
conditional statement AND formatting
to check and see if my formatting needed to change.
I'm sure it's simple and looking forward to thoughts.
Thank you in advance.
UPDATE:
I made the changes that BigBen suggested, but it is still evaluating into this even though prog_soft_dev_comp is only equal to 1. See image below:


You likely need some parentheses, e.g. (acc_comp >= 21 And acc_comp <= 25)... (auto_tech_comp >= 21 And auto_tech_comp <= 23).

Good suggestion @BigBen, but even after making those changes it's still evaluating.  See my update above.

Then one (or more) of the other conditions not related to prog_soft_dev_comp is true.

I'll sift through them and see, thank you for your help today and yesterday.

If graph_comm_comp = 0, then (graph_comm_comp >= 21 Or graph_comm_comp <= 23) is true. You need And, not Or.

Sifted through all of the variables and they are all zero except for prog_soft_dev_comp.  When I run through with F8 it is still evaluating. I will include the top of the code for more clarity.

Same problem with health_sci_comp.

@BigBen Aw! There it is. Thank you! I'll change those lines that if the "Or's" in them.

@cybernetic.nomad They are only integers, but for that statement it can be equal to 21, 22, or 23.

Doh! you're right
